# PHP Compare 2 multidimensional arrays and get non matching items

Tags: php

I'm trying to get non matching items between 2 multidimensional arrays using the 'nombre_entrada', 'precio_productor' and 'id_funcion' to compare. I tried with array_search/array_column but didn't work.

What I need is to get a new array containing the items not matching.

**Array 1**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 250
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 300
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 350
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => 2 entradas x
            [precio_productor] => 400
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 350
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => 2 entradas x
            [precio_productor] => 400
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

)
```

In the Array 1 index 0 and 1 not exists in Array 2 so I need to create a final array including those items.

**Final Array**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 250
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre_entrada] => Entrada General
            [precio_productor] => 300
            [id_funcion] => 907
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally the functionality of `array_diff`.

You can't use `array_diff` for it directly because it compares the string representation of the array items to find the difference, and arrays don't have a distinct string representation. (They all just convert to "Array".)

PHP can compare arrays though, and if you use `array_udiff` you can just compare them directly in the comparison function without converting to string.

```
$result = array_udiff($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather tricky solution, it works only inf you need compare **all 3 keys** and if order of keys in all subarray are the same:

```
// first rebuild second array to new array 
// where key is serialized value of value:
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array2 as $item) {
    $newArray[serialize($item)] = $item;
}

// next - filter your first array:
$filteredArray = array_filter(
    $array1,
    function($v) use ($newArray) {
        // here serialize `$v` and check if key 
        // same as serialized `$v` exists in $newArray
        return !isset($newArray[serialize($v)]);
    }
);
```

Working fiddle https://3v4l.org/aKba9.

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder your code is working. At the same time you answered my question I found another way to get the solution.

Comment: @Nacho, even if you were able to manage to find a solution in the meantime, please acknowledge the effort put in by someone on SO to come up with another working solution. They still put in their time and brain cycles, so please consider marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the array in this way

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($detectadas as $item) {
    if ( 
        array_search($item['nombre_entrada'], array_column($entradasResult2, 'nombre_entrada')) === false OR
        array_search($item['precio_productor'], array_column($entradasResult2, 'precio_productor')) === false OR
        array_search($item['id_funcion'], array_column($entradasResult2, 'id_funcion')) === false
    ) {
        array_push( $newArray, $item );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_filter` with [`!in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), which accepts an array as the `$needle` argument. It works similarly to `array_udiff($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; })`, but will disregard the array keys, is compatible with PHP 5.3+ and does not need to iterate over the source array with `serialize()` which would be costly with a very large array.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/DdSf1

```
$array1 = array(
    array
    (
        'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
        'precio_productor' => 250,
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    ),
    array
    (
        'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
        'precio_productor' => 300,
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    ),
    array
    (
        'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
        'precio_productor' => 350,
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    ),
    array
    (
        'nombre_entrada' => '2 entradas x',
        'precio_productor' => 400,
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    )
);
$array2 = array(
    array
    (
        'precio_productor' => 350, //note array key was moved
        'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    ),
    array
    (
        'nombre_entrada' => '2 entradas x',
        'precio_productor' => 400,
        'id_funcion' => 907,
    ),
);
```

```
$missing = array_filter($array1, function($v) use ($array2) {
    return !in_array($v, $array2);
});

var_export($missing);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
    'precio_productor' => 250,
    'id_funcion' => 907,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'nombre_entrada' => 'Entrada General',
    'precio_productor' => 300,
    'id_funcion' => 907,
  ),
)
```

Alternatively If you want to account for the array keys, you can pass true as the third argument to `in_array($v, $array2, true)`, which will cause a strict comparison, which is equivalent to `$a <=> $b`.

---

As a simpler solution using `serialize`, instead of iterating over the array, you can compare the values directly using `array_udiff` and `strcmp`. Though I recommend using `$a <=> $b` ([spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op)) instead if you have PHP 7.0+

https://3v4l.org/ErtCp

```
$missing = array_udiff($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(serialize($a), serialize($b));
});
```